# Crystal Reports - Displaying customer records who have not bought

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

amazing experts.

I am still very new to Crystal, and only do it on the odd occasion, and seem to be going around in circles with this issue.
I work for a charity, and we would like to pull off a list of all our past donors who have not donated anything on the last 6 months.
I have tables for customer details, linked to another tables which shows their orders. They are linked based on the unique customer ID.

I have added all the customer orders, grouped by customer ID and then sported by OrderDate, and now I get stuck.

In my mind, I need to exclude anyone who has an order date that is less than 6 months old, and to do so I have tried using
{OrderDate} <= DateAdd ("m", -6, CurrentDate).

This however only seems to remove the customer orders that are less than 6 months old, not remove the customer records themselves.
I have tried using it both the "Select Expert" and also to suppress in the "Section Expert", but neither seem to be working to exclude the relevant Customer records.

I am certain there is a super easy way to do this, and I will kick myself when I know how to do it, but right now I have gone round the houses trying to find the solution.
So, if anyone out there has done this before and can help me out, i would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: can you post the sql generated from crystal?

Comment: Hello maSTA rHiAn,
First of all, thank you for your reply, and sorry I did not respond yesterday. Working on reports is only a very small part of my riole, and as such gets squeezed out on busy days.
Sorry, but I am uncertain what you mean. How do I do that?
As I said before, I am still very new to Crystal, and have not been shown/told how to do see the SQL that a report generates.
If I have time to do an internet search for this before you reply, I will, and I will post the SQL as soon as I know how.
Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is the SQL as requested:  <br/>  <br/>
SELECT DISTINCT "SL_ACCOUNTS"."CUCODE", "SL_ACCOUNTS"."CUNAME", "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_GROSS", "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_HEADER_REF", "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_TYPE", "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_DATE"
 FROM   "DBname"."dbo"."SL_PL_NL_DETAIL" "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL" INNER JOIN "DBname"."dbo"."SL_ACCOUNTS" "SL_ACCOUNTS" ON "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_ACCOUNT"="SL_ACCOUNTS"."CUCODE"
 WHERE  "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_TYPE"='INV'
 ORDER BY "SL_ACCOUNTS"."CUCODE", "SL_PL_NL_DETAIL"."DET_HEADER_REF" DESC  <br/>  <br/>
I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem.

create a running summary field to count the number of rows return per group. if it is zero under the group section, under suppress , edit formula at put  > 0

and run the report.

Comment: Hello,  Thank you very much, but where in that do I specify a date range?  Because that is part of the problem I am facing. I do not know how to only show those customers who have **not** had an invoice in the last 6 months, but when I use DateAdd it returns everyone's orders that are 6 months or older, even for those who have orders in those 6 months.  Perhaps I am not explaining it properly?

Comment: At the groupheader section

Comment: Thank you ever so much, @maSTA rHiAn.  That is exactly what I needed. It seems that Crystal will still include the orders that are after the 6 month range specified, but because the group is, they are not included in the shown result. I think I'm done with it...finally.  Thank you again for taking the time to help me resolve this.